# DayofWeek, Year & Shiftname

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize if my questions seems irrelevant or silly. My expertise on SQL is low.

My questions is that I'm trying to create five columns namely ID, shiftName, DayofWeek, date & year in the database.dbo.tablename. However, I'm not sure and couldn't find the right source to correctly write queries for this.
The logic is a day will have 6 shifts, so the DayofWeek, date and year should correspond to the shift column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which DBMS are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: Usually a `date` value includes the day, month, and year. I think adding an extra column `year` could be redundant.

Comment: Are you wanting to create a new table composed of these five columns, or are you trying to ADD these five columns to a table that already exists?

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simple table I could think of, that would work in MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, or DB2:

```
create table tablename (
  id int primary key not null,
  shift_name varchar(40) not null,
  day_of_week int not null,
  "date" date not null
);
```

I excluded the column `year` since the column `date` already includes the day, month, and year.

Comment: how can I populate this fields which date starting 1/01/2017?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: If you're going to leave `year` out, you might as well leave out `day_of_week` also, since it's only a scalar function away if you have a date.

Comment: My bad, sorry for my ignorance.. trying to learn this stuff now.. I'm using SQL Server database.